# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You can’t update hidden events because they contain essential event-series data - What are hidden events?

Tags: apex, event, insufficient-privileges

We all know what INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY means, but this is my first time encountering this particular error in all my years of working with Salesforce.

`INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You can’t update hidden events because they contain essential event-series data`

My code is already filtering to only try to update Events that are not child events and are related to a customer (Account and/or Contact).

What is a 'hidden event', and how can I make sure my code doesn't attempt to update them?

Comment: what fields are you changing in the update?

Comment: Only one custom field, called CallRecordId__c

Comment: Interesting question! Although I haven't found anything concrete in the documentation but my best guess is you are trying to edit a recurring event or so called event series.

Comment: @pk1772 are you aware of any way for us to identify and ignore events from a series in our query? I'm only aware of isChild.

Comment: @MorganMarchese this would be the field in Lightning Experience - `IsRecurrence2`. You can check more on the DEV guide - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm